# Structure for Admin Panel and User Panel

Tags: cakephp, structure

I want to make my project by using Cakephp. Can I make Structure like that with setting of route: /   (This is for User Panel)
       /admin (This is for Admin Panel)

Controller:
           UsersController
           AdminsController
Model:
           admin

View: 
           Users> List of users view
           Admins>List of admin View

Comment: Please explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to have something like:

- www.example.com/videos/index/
- www.example.com/admin/videos/index/

What you are looking for is [prefix-routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)

**Howto**

In your `app/Config/core.php` add/uncomment the following:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Now, instead of making a link like so:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Videos index', array('controller' => 'videos', 'action' => 'index'));
# Output: http://www.example.com/videos/index
```

You add the admin prefix:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Videos index', array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'videos', 'action' => 'index'));
# Output: http://www.example.com/admin/videos/index
```

*Note that your method will be called `VideosController::admin_index()` and the view is called `admin_index.ctp`*

**More about routing:**

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html